# FsCheck not using registered Arbs/Gens

Tags: f#, xunit, fscheck, property-based-testing

I am trying to use FsCheck for Property based testing but I cannot seem to figure out how to get FsCheck to use the gens I have registered. Here is the code for generating types for the domain:

```ml
module Flips.Gens

open Flips.Domain
open FsCheck

type Silly = {
    Name : string
}

let SillyGen () =
    gen {
        let! NonEmptyString name = Arb.generate<NonEmptyString>
        return { Name = name}
    }

type Domain () =
    static member ArbSillyGen () = Arb.fromGen (SillyGen ())
```

Here is the example test

```ml
module Flips.Tests

open Xunit
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit
open Flips.Gens

do Arb.register<Domain> () |> ignore

module Tests =

    [<Property>]
    let ``Silly Name is NonEmptyString`` (silly:Silly) =
        let isNullOrEmpty = System.String.IsNullOrEmpty silly.Name
        Assert.True(not isNullOrEmpty)
```

I have two problems:

1. It does not appear that FsCheck is using the generators I have provided because it is generating `Silly` types with a name that is empty.
2. I try setting a breakpoint in the gen for the `Silly` type but it is never hit so I can't figure out what is going on.

I've done this before in other projects but for some reason I'm hitting a brick wall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FsCheck + xunit handles arbitraries in a different way. Per the documentation [here](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/RunningTests.html#Using-FsCheck-Xunit), I would try and run the test this way:

module Tests =

```
[<Property(Arbitrary = [| typeof<Domain> |] )>]
let ``Silly Name is NonEmptyString`` (silly:Silly) =
    let isNullOrEmpty = System.String.IsNullOrEmpty silly.Name
    Assert.True(not isNullOrEmpty)
```

You can delete `do Arb.register<Domain> () |> ignore`

Comment: This also works, and it is applied to all the properties ```[<assembly: Properties( Arbitrary = [| typeof<Domain> |] )>] do()```

Comment: I was unaware of that method, thanks @ArialdoMartini